# Accessing static data

Tags: android, xml, sqlite, csv, flat-file

What is the best way to access static data for an Android app

**Information about the data**

- Will be read-only, the user cannot change it
- Data will consist of an ID, and a few words/short phrases
- It won't be huge: maximum of about 1000 words/short phrases
- The data will be accessed sequentially
- I will have the data while developing the app
- The data will be read frequently

**From what I've read on the web so far, I have a few options:**

1. Load all the static data into an SQLite database when the app starts. This is the secure way of doing it because then only rooted users can delete/change data. Also, Android allready has SQLite and querying is easy. Can be read sequentially with `cursor.moveToNext()` method
2. Read the data from a flat/xml/csv file from within the app's resources. I don't know how the speed of reading from a file compares to using SQLite? Also, if I've got to reference to a  particular line (which will be a word/phrase) in the file, what is the difference between that and just hardcoding it?

**What is the best option? Are there better solutions?**

Comment: if the data is not structured then you can put it in strings.xml or arrays.xml

Answer (score 1):

You can put your static data in values/strings.xml file.
It is best way if you don't have huge data and user can not change it.

Answer (score 1):

```
static final data ? :
```

The common way to do it in android , is to create a file called `strings.xml` under `/res` in your application, and to put your strings there. every string has a name. exemple :

```
<string name="app_name">Single Finder</string>
```

Then you can access to your strings from your XML layouts or from your java sources. exemple :

**XML**:

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

**Java**:

```
String myStr = getApplicationContext().getRessources().getString(R.string.hello_world);
```

Another way, which is the Java common way to create `static final` strings. see [Declaring a Variable as a Constant](http://java.about.com/od/understandingdatatypes/a/Using-Constants.htm).